# jquery/javascript, variable scope issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is probably a really noob question but I can't see what the problem here is returning the variable `pic_real_width.`

I presume it's a scope thing, but other than making it global (can't do that) I'm unsure how i can set and return it.

Thanks in advance,

```
function get_real_width(img){
    var pic_real_width;
    $("<img/>") // Make in memory copy of image to avoid css issues
      .attr("src", $(img).attr("src"))
      .load(function() {
         pic_real_width = this.width;   
         console.log( pic_real_width ); // returns a number
       });
   console.log( pic_real_width ); //returns undefined
   return pic_real_width;
}
```

Comment: Look up async vs sync.

Comment: the second `console.log(pic_real_width)` is running before the `.load()` function is. put your return statement at the end of the load function.

Comment: Asynchronous task is asyncronous !

Comment: try console.log(this.width) first and check if it's defined

Comment: It's has something to do with blocking and non-blocking operations, I think. The `.load()` method is non-blocking so it allows the lines of code after it to execute even though it is still not executed. That's why you're getting undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, the function you pass to load is async, and async functions have a different context of the pattern function.

In the example, a solution can't be encountered (i can't find a solution for it now), but, you  can refactor your code to get the "real width" of the image asynchronous, just passing other callback that's called inside the function passed to load().

Something such as:

```
function get_real_width(img, callback){
    var pic_real_width;
    $("<img/>") // Make in memory copy of image to avoid css issues
    .attr("src", $(img).attr("src"))
    .load(function() {
        pic_real_width = this.width;   
        callback( img, pic_real_width ); // Call the function with the number expected
    });
}
```

As it just get the width and return it to a function.

But, i know, it cannot be used in some situation.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your function will have exited before the .load call is done, therefore there is no value to return.

The 'pic_real_width' is set during the callback function for the load, but meanwhile, your function continues to execute while it waits for the .load to finish, and therefore exits, before the value has been set.

Answer (score 0):

`.load` is attaching a `load` event handler to the image and that event *might* get fired asynchronously (it could be synchronous if the browser cached the image), wich means the `.load` call returns right away and the handler will not have been executed yet when you reach `return pic_real_width;`.

However, you can make use of [`$.Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) to solve this issue in an elegant way.

```
function get_real_width(img){
    var def = $.Deferred();
    $("<img/>")
      .load(function() {
         def.resolve(this.width);
       })
      .attr("src", $(img).attr("src"));
    return def;
}

get_real_width().done(function (width) {
    console.log(width);
});
```

*Please note that I attached the handler before setting the source in case the image was cached and the event gets fired synchronously*.

Answer (score 0):

In English, this is what `get_real_width` is currently doing:

1. Create a local variable called `pic_real_width`.
2. Create a new `<img/>` element with the copied src attribute, and **once** that `<img/>` element is loaded, **then** run the inner function. The "once/then" part is what everyone is describing as asynchronous, since you don't know or have any control over when this is going to happen relative to the rest of your code.
3. Immediately log and return `pic_real_width`.

Note that `pic_real_width` will only be set once the inner function is called and finishes, but that probably will not happened by the time `get_real_width` exits, so `pic_real_width` will be undefined when you log and return it.

So, how do you fix this?

That depends on how you're using the result of `get_real_width`. If, for example, you were creating an alert from the result of `get_real_width`, like this:

```
alert(get_real_width(some_img));
```

Then, you could instead modify your function so that the alert is happening inside function attached to .load:

```
function alert_real_width(img){
    $("<img/>")
      .attr("src", $(img).attr("src"))
      .load(function() {
         var pic_real_width = this.width;   
         alert( pic_real_width );
       });
}
```

Obviously, I doubt you're doing an `alert`, but that should give you an idea of how to approach the problem. For a more general solution, you can use a callback like other users have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Returning the promise is just a "little bit" better...

```
function get_real_width(img, callback) {
    var dfd= $.Deferred(function (dfd) {

        $("<img/>")
            .attr("src", $(img).attr("src"))
            .load(function () {
                dfd.resolve(this.width);
            });
    });

    return dfd.promise();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, an `ajax()` request is asynchronous so the call to `ajax()` will usually return before the request completes. You could make use of a callback function instead.

```
function get_real_width(img, callback){
    var pic_real_width;
    $("<img/>") // Make in memory copy of image to avoid css issues
    .attr("src", $(img).attr("src"))
    .load(function() {
        pic_real_width = this.width;   
        callback(pic_real_width ); // Call the function with the number expected
    });
}

 get_real_width(img, function(returnedData){ //anonymous callback function        
    console.log(myVariable);
    return returnedData;
 });
```

If you absolutely must, you could use [`async: false` inside the call to `ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).